# How does the -m switch work in Perl

Tags: perl

If you could explain the flow and how/why we can create a module to run with -Mm it will be helpful

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`-Mfoo` simply generates the code `use foo;` and places it at the beginning of the code to be compiled.

`-mfoo` generates `use foo ();`

`-Mfoo=bar,baz` generates `use foo ('bar','baz');` and so does `-mfoo=bar,baz` -- that is, there stops being a difference between `-M` and `-m` when you use the form with an equal sign, but without it, `-m` generates the "non-import" form of `use`.

This is all [documented in perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches).

Comment: thanks. but does will any module get executed thus or does it need to have a import subroutine?

Comment: @DotDot: A module does not need an import routine.